# kubernetes: how to link secret tls crt/key with files or configMap?

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to link secret tls crt/key with files?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: hello-app-tls
  namespace: dev
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt: <crt_filePath>
  tls.key: <key_filePath>
```

Or reference values from a ConfigMap like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: hello-app-tls
  namespace: dev
type: kubernetes.io/tls
data:
  tls.crt:
    valueFrom:
       configMapKeyRef:
         name: configmap_tls
         key: crt
  tls.key:
    valueFrom:
       configMapKeyRef:
         name: configmap_tls
         key: key
```

Error:

```
Secret in version "v1" cannot be handled as a Secret: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go struct field Secret.data of type []uint8
```